# WIth Nginx do I have to add a content-security-policy to every location block?

Tags: nginx, digital-ocean

**Environment:** Nginx, Node.js, Digital Ocean Droplet

The docs for the [add_header](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_header) directive indicate that it can be used in an `http`, `server` or `location` context.

However when I add my [content-security-policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) to either the `http` or `server` context it isn't detected when I test it at https://csp-evaluator.withgoogle.com/ or https://securityheaders.com/.
When I add it to a `location` block both sites detect it.

**Example header:**

```
add_header content-security-policy "default-src 'self';"
```

My `nginx.conf` has 5 `location` blocks, one being used as a proxy.  Do I need to add `content-security-policy` to every block or is there a better way?

```
location ~* \.(jpg|png|svg|webp|ico)$ { }
location ~* \.(css)$ { }
location ~* \.(htm|html)$ { }
location ~* \.(js)$ { }
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9999;
}
```

Also do I need to add all of my other main security headers to each block?  It seems redundant but if that's the only way to secure the site I'll do it.

- [feature-policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Feature-Policy)
- [permissions-policy](https://scotthelme.co.uk/goodbye-feature-policy-and-hello-permissions-policy/)
- [referrer-policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy)
- [strict-transport-security](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Strict-Transport-Security)
- [x-content-type-options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Content-Type-Options)

Comment: Are those `location` blocks really empty?!

Comment: @MichaelHampton no my real location blocks have content.  I didn't include it to save space.  My actual content-security-policy is 300 characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `add_header` directive has an interesting property. From the [documentation](https://nginx.org/r/add_header):

> There could be several `add_header` directives. These directives are inherited from the previous configuration level if and only if there are no `add_header` directives defined on the current level.

This means if you are adding *other* headers in one of those `location` blocks, then any `add_header` directives from the `server` or `http` blocks would need to be repeated.

Consider using `include`d files to organize directives like this that you may need to repeat.

Comment: Yep, all of my location blocks have `cache-control` headers and that must have stopped the propagation.  That's an unintuitive feature I read the docs several times and never caught that.  Great catch!  I'll look into `include` files and see if that might help.  I hate to repeat code.